How to add packages to Graalvm python polyglot?
I followed the StackOverflow question Here and the subsequent link https://medium.com/graalvm/truffle-unchained-13887b77b62c in order to setup a working example of running Python from a Spring Boot App.
While the example works good, I am not sure how I can add packages if my python program requires any.
Here's an excerpt from my pom.xml where I have the polyglot dependencies:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.graalvm.polyglot</groupId>
    <artifactId>python</artifactId>
    <version>23.1.0</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>

I have a simple Python code in posts.py which does this:
def fetch_posts():
    url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
    try:
        with request.urlopen(url) as response:
            if response.status == 200:
                source = response.read()
                posts = json.loads(source)
                return posts
            else:
                print("Failed to fetch posts due to HTTP error.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        return None

Given that I've put this file in src/main/resources/python/posts.py, I'm successfully able to call this from my Java code:
@Test
void testPythonScript2() throws IOException {
    ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("python/posts.py");
    try (Context context = Context.newBuilder().allowAllAccess(true).build()) {
        Source source = Source.newBuilder("python", resource.getFile()).build();
        context.eval(source);
        Value pyObject = context.getBindings("python").getMember("fetch_posts");

        Value result = pyObject.execute();
        assertTrue(result.hasArrayElements());
        assertEquals(100, result.getArraySize());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(),e);
        assertFalse(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(),e);
        assertFalse(true);
    }
}

This test passes.
But, what do I do, if posts.py needs the numpy package? How do I install it?
I'm using graalvm-jdk-21.0.3+7.1 as the underlying JDK.
Thanks,
Sriram

Since we are using polyglot as a python interpreter from java, it doesn't have any information about the python virtual environment when loading the python script file.
The graalpython project can be used to work around this issue. But please note that your required python dependencies should have patch for graalpy inorder to use it successfully. You can check which all packages are compatible here.
Install graalpython
Follow the instructions given here to install graalpy for your OS.
I used pyenv ( python version manager ) to install graalpy
pyenv install graalpy-24.0.1

Create virtual environment using graalpy
graalpy -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate

Install required python dependencies
graalpy -m pip install requests

Please note that steps for creating virtual environment and installing the dependencies can be added as a maven build step. It is given in this article
Execute python script from java using polyglot
Context context = Context.newBuilder("python").
                allowAllAccess(true).
                option("python.PythonPath", "<python-project-path>").
                option("python.ForceImportSite", "true").
                option("python.Executable", "<python-project-path>/.venv/bin/python").
                build();

Source source = Source.newBuilder("python", new File("<python-project-path>/test.py"))
                .build();
context.eval(source);


More details are given in this blog.
